# jsoup quotes and spaces

Tags: jsoup

I am trying to pick, using Jsoup, the paragraph inside the following HTML snippet:

```
<div class="abc ">
<p class="de">Very short paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

For that, I am using the following Java code snippet:

```
Elements divs = document.select("div[class=abc ]");
for (Element div : divs) {
  Log.v("iwashere", String.format("div[class=abc ]"));
  Elements ppp = document.select("p[class=de]");                   
  for (Element p : ppp) {
    Log.v("iwashere", p.text());
    break;                                                
  } 
}
```

The problem is that, for some reason, Jsoup doesn't seem to pick up the "div[class=abc ]" (the Log.v("iwashere") never shows up in the log.

At first, I thought that the trailing space may be a problem, so I also tried

```
Elements divs = document.select("div[class=abc]");
```

but that didn't help either.

What could be the problem in the above code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jsoup use css selectors.  You want to use "div.abc", which means a div with a class of abc.

```
Element divs = document.select("div.abc");
```

Comment: Thanks. I am confused: can't "class" be regarded as attribute of div? i.e. as in the syntax described here: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax I am trying to understand what went wrong with my understanding because I could swear that I had it working win class ids that don't have trailing spaces.

Comment: Yes, class is can be used as attribute of div.  However, your HTML has "class=abc ", note the trailing space.  "div[class=abc ]" is treated as "div[class=abc]", i.e. jsoup is ignoring spaces, so the select nevers finds the div.  Using "div.abc" avoids all these issues.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and the results confirm your explanation. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug with the whitespace at the end of "abc**_**" (where "_" is a whitespace).

Elements divs = document.select("div[class=abc ]");

That's why it's working with the css selectors (div.abc).

Comment: I had to select a div with a class that had a space in its name: `<div class="two words">`, and the solution you provided did the trick (`"div[class=two words]"`). Thanks